# How to get Url.action to produce the action method name

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Why doesn't this call to action provide the action method name?

```
@Url.Action("Index","NewStore")
```

It just produces...

```
localhost/TemplateUI/en-CA/Atomic/Wassabi/Store
```

I need it to produce the /index on the end....

Answer (score 1):

That's because the `Url.Action` helper uses your route registration in Global.asax. And since you are passing `Index` as action name I guess that in your route registration you have specified that the default value for `action="Index"`, so it is omitted.

For example if you have the following default route:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{controller}/{action}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
    );
}
```

since the `controller = "Home"` and `action = "Index"` constraints have been specified both `/` and `/Home` will be absolutely equivalent urls and invoke the `Index` action of `Home` controller.

So the same happens when you try to build an url with some of the helpers : it uses your routes.

If you need to have the action name in the url make sure you have removed the `action` constraint in your route definition.